# How do i make content (Fusion Chart LED Gauge Chart) inside table to be responsive?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, fusioncharts

I have requirement wherein i need to show 3 chart inside the table, each chart in each TD.

Note that the Table is Re-sizeable , the chart inside each TD has be responsive (atleast width wise). Currently in the fiddle Table is re-sizeable by increasing the output window, but chart inside it is not getting resized. I want the Widget to be proportionate the TD Height and width

I don't want to achieve it using JS. Can it be done using just CSS/Bootstrap ?

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Device</th>
        <th>CPU</th>
        <th>Memory</th>
        <th>Temp</th>
      </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="icn"></td>
        <td class="device">Note 2</td>
        <td class="fchart" id="chart-container"></td>
        <td class="fchart" id="chart-container1"></td>
        <td class="fchart" id="chart-container2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="icn"></td>
        <td class="device">Moto G</td>
        <td class="fchart" id="chart-container3"></td>
        <td class="fchart" id="chart-container4"></td>
        <td class="fchart" id="chart-container5"></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="icn"></td>
        <td class="device">Redmi Note 4</td>
        <td class="fchart" id="chart-container6"></td>
        <td class="fchart" id="chart-container7"></td>
        <td class="fchart" id="chart-container8"></td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

Below is my mockup:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bq9gM/12/)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a work around to meet your requirement.

FusionCharts container width and height can be provided in percentage (%) You can try this.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Device</th>
        <th>CPU</th>
        <th>Memory</th>
        <th>Temp</th>
      </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="icn"></td>
            <td class="device">Note 2</td>
            <td >
               <div class="fchart" id="chart-container"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="fchart" id="chart-container1"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="fchart" id="chart-container2"></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="icn"></td>
            <td class="device">Moto G</td>
            <td>
                <div class="fchart" id="chart-container3"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="fchart" id="chart-container4"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="fchart" id="chart-container5"></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td class="icn"></td>
            <td class="device">Redmi Note 4</td>
            <td>
                <div class="fchart" id="chart-container6"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="fchart" id="chart-container7"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="fchart" id="chart-container8"></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t0s0zkwL/)

Comment: within answers, you can ommit "@Sharath", because the OP will be notified autmatically.